# Does Apache read-lock files before serving them?

Tags: php, json, apache, locking

I have an mobile app that reads a JSON file that is stored on an Apache server.  The contents of that JSON file are regenerated (using a PHP script) if something is changed via a GUI.

I am worried that trying to overwrite the JSON file in the middle of it being served by Apache might cause problems.

Does Apache obtain a read lock before serving files?  If not, what will happen if I try to write it at the same time it is being served?

Comment: Do you really need a 'physical' file or can you just fake the file by just outputting the contents?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. On POSIX-compatible systems, all locks are advisory anyways, so even if apache would get a read lock, the other process could just write the file.

You can determine that with `strace`:

```
[pid  7246] open("/var/www/file.json", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 11
[pid  7246] fcntl(11, F_GETFD)          = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
[pid  7246] mmap(NULL, 20, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 11, 0) = 0x7f53f93da000
[pid  7246] munmap(0x7f53f93da000, 20)  = 0
[pid  7246] writev(10, [{"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Thu, 26 J"}, ...) = 365
[pid  7246] close(11)                   = 0
```

Therefore, it can happen that your JSON file is only partially written. To avoid this problem, write your JSON file to a temporary file on the same filesystem, and use the atomic `rename` to overwrite the file.

That way, if the `open` has succeeded, apache will continue serving the old file. If the `rename` finishes before the `open`, apache will get the new, completed file.

If you worry about consistency (in the case of a power failure or so), you may also want to call [`fsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) in the application that writes the JSON file before closing it.

Comment: If I used PHP's http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php and got a write lock, would that be OK?

Comment: @cdmckay No, a write lock has no effect, since apache doesn't get a read lock. I extended the answer. In short: use [`rename`](http://php.net/rename).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why doesn't Apache read-lock them?  Performance?

Comment: @cdmckay Well, why should apache read-lock them? Remember, all [features start at -100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx), especially if they incur prohibitive performance costs, as flock does.

Answer (score 4):

You're thinking in the wrong paradigm for *nix platforms.  What you want are atomic file writes to the JSON file in your script.  You do this by writing the file to a unique temporary filename in the target directory then using `rename()` to move this file over the old one.  The file move operation is atomic.  Asynchronous processes will either open the old JSON file or the new one but not a hybrid.

There are various ways to construct a temporary filename. See the PHP documentation user comments on `tempnam()`.  My system generates a request unique ID, so I just use `$_SERVER["UNIQUE_ID"]` as the base.